# Jinja template in Airflow always change value to String

Tags: python, jinja2, airflow

I have a custom defined Operator `my_previous_job` in Airflow that returns a Python list.

In my DAG definition, I reference it using jinja template:

```
t_my_job = MyOperator(
    data=json.dumps({
        "jobId": f"{{{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='my_previous_job', "f"key='return_value')}}}}",
    })
)
```

However, the value the `f"{{{{ (ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='my_previous_job', "f"key='return_value')}}}})"` returns is not a list, but a string with a list in it. i.e.

Instead of:

```
      ['a','b','c']
```

it returns a string:

```
      "['a','b','c']"
```

What can I do to just get the list generated by the `my_previous_job` instead of a String?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Airflow < 2.1.0: Rendering templated fields is always string.

For Airflow >= 2.1.0:
There is support for rendering fields as native Python Objects.
You will need to set `render_template_as_native_obj=True` in the DAG object.
You can read more about it in the [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/operators.html#rendering-fields-as-native-python-objects).