# How to get an Xcom value from a previous task

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer, airflow-xcom

I am trying to get the Xcom value from a Sensor task. This is the result of the Sensor task:

[image: Xcom value]

Now, I want to retrieve the string 'df-00...' si I can use it in the ***InputFilePattern*** parameter as you can see in the following task:

```
    dataflow_gcs_to_bq = DataflowTemplatedJobStartOperator(
    task_id='',
    template='',
    job_name='',
    location='',
    project_id='',
    parameters={
        'javascriptTextTransformFunctionName': '',
        'JSONPath': '',
        'javascriptTextTransformGcsPath': '',
        'inputFilePattern': 'HERE',
        'outputTable': '',
        'bigQueryLoadingTemporaryDirectory': '',
    },        
)
```

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I proposed you an answer. Can you check it please and tell me if it helps you to solve your issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Since [parameters](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1e7c064560b8504b45e3a53dc8f294b143b4ec7d/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/dataflow.py#L603) is templated field you can do it directly with Jinja.

Assuming previous `task_id` is `previous_task` then the code will be:

```
dataflow_gcs_to_bq = DataflowTemplatedJobStartOperator(
    ...,
    parameters={
        "inputFilePattern": "{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='previous_task') }}",
        ...,
    },
)
```

Note: Jinja render as string by default. In your example I see that the value is list so you might also need to set `render_template_as_native_obj` to render the value as native python object see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70806922/14624409) for more information.

Comment: I tried something similar but I got "None", I do not know what I am doing wrong.

I tried:
'inputFilePattern': 'gs://bucket/df/{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids="gcs_sensor")}}'
Also, since I have a list in the Xcom value I tried doing:
'inputFilePattern': 'gs://bucket/df/{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids="gcs_sensor", key="return_value")[0]}}'

Answer (score 1):

I propose an answer in addition to Elad's, if you have custom treatments to apply on the value retrieved from the previous task using `xcom`.

You can create a custom operator that extends `DataflowTemplatedJobStartOperator`, example :

```py
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.dataflow import DataflowTemplatedJobStartOperator


class CustomDataflowTemplatedJobStartOperator(DataflowTemplatedJobStartOperator):

    def __init__(
            self,
            task_id,
            template,
            job_name,
            location,
            project_id,
            parameters,
    ) -> None:
        super(CustomDataflowTemplatedJobStartOperator, self) \
            .__init__(
            task_id=task_id,
            template=template,
            job_name=job_name,
            location=location,
            project_id=project_id,
            parameters=parameters)

    def execute(self, context):
        task_instance = context['task_instance']
        input_file_pattern_xcom = task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='previous_task_id')

        # Add the input retrieved from xcom and add it to the parameters Dict.
        self.parameters['inputFilePattern'] = input_file_pattern_xcom

        super(CustomDataflowTemplatedJobStartOperator, self).execute(context)
```

We override `execute` method and retrieve the value with `xcom` from the previous task, via the current `context`.

Then you can apply transformations on this value if needed and add the entry to the Dict `parameters` on the current operator.

You can instantiate your custom operator as usual operators :

```py
CustomDataflowTemplatedJobStartOperator(
    task_id="my_task",
    template="my_template",
    job_name="my_job_name",
    location="my_location",
    project_id="project_id",
    parameters={    
        'param1': 'paramValue1'
    }
)
```